# Trignometric functions and their polynomial forms

Tags: trigonometric-series

The trigonometric values also has a infinite series which I had learnt from the topics of Limits

> Sin x = x - x³/ 3! + x⁵/ 5!.......

There are formulas like these for other trigonometric functions too. But here's where I don't understand. If we substitute 'π' instead of 'x' , then by using this formula , we get sin π not zero when it is zero. Similarly for all sin values of nπ ,where n ∈ Z get into the same trap.

sinπ = π - π³/3! + π⁵/5!...

0    = π - π³/3! + π⁵/5! ...

L.H.S ≠ R.H.S

This shouldn't happen, right ?

Where did I go wrong, then ?

Comment: that's the wrong series, first term is x

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html

Comment: Oh, thank you for clearing that. Can you explain about how sinπ is zero by using the series. Is it by limiting method ?

Comment: Your last equation is wrong. Please read a little bit more about limits, sequences and series. There's no "polynomial form" for trigonometric functions. The three dots are very important, you can't forget about them. Learn what they mean

Comment: I'm really sorry for that. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p (-1)^n \frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ For $p=4$, $S_4=0.00692527$, for $p=5$, $S_5=-0.00044516$, for $p=6$, $S_6=0.0000211426$.

Comment: So the value of sin π tends to zero. Is that what you mean, @Claude Leibovici ?